# Using radvd to advertise ipv6 over VPN connection using DD-wrt

Tags: vpn, ipv6, router

My ultimate goal is to allow VPN users to have access to my internal IPv6 network from across the intertubes.  I've got a linksys WRT54GSv2 running DD-WRTv24SP1 and have configured the little guy as specified here http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6 and it works wonderfully over the br0 interface (LAN/WLAN bridge).

Here's the issue though, when I add an additional interface to the radvd config file on the router (specifically ppp0, for the VPN traffic), radvd refuses to start.  The kicker is that on DDWRT, it doesn't give an error message, it just fails outright.

Any suggestions on where to proceed from here?

/jffs/radvd.conf:

```
interface br0 {
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   prefix 0:0:0:1::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
   };
};
interface ppp0 {
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   prefix 0:0:0:1::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
   };
};
```

The documentation I've found for radvd is slim, but if anyone has a decent idea on how to proceed I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IPv6 addresses are assigned to br0 and ppp0? You might try changing the prefixes in radvd.conf to match them.

According to [the radvd.conf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/radvd.conf), the prefix 0:0:0:XXXX::/64 is used for 6to4. I don't think duplicate prefixes are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close the question as my ultimate intention was to be able to have IPv6 access through a VPN tunnel as I traveled.  My tunnel provider (Hurricane Electric) has just added this feature in the last few days.

I'm going to accept Gerald's answer as that solved the immediate problem at hand.  Thanks!